# Any packages for graph plot?

Tags: ros, rospackage, plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

Is there any packages available with ROS for 2d or 3d plotting of mathematical data (if possible, something similar to matlab plotting) ?

NOTE: I need to access the c++ output data dynamically for plotting.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68095/any-packages-for-graph-plot?/) by [chris_chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2965/chris_chris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS has basic plotting abilities thanks to `rxplot` in http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxplot and `rqt_plot` here http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_plot but you can always write your 'plotting' node in python and then use the excellent `matplotlib` which can do practically everything matlab can in terms of plotting.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2013-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris_chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2965/chris_chris/) on 2013-07-22**:
But 'matplotlib' is in python. I need to access the c++ outputs dynamically.
and Is there any with c++ ? or Is it possible to use matplotlib for accessing c++ outputs dynamically ?

**Comment by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) on 2013-07-23**:
You can also 'program' `gnuplot` inside a c++ code. But resort to this only when the `rqt` and `rxplot` utils do not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@chris_chris do you need GUI tools OR API?

`*_plot` @makokal suggested work for the former purpose.

Decoding the source code of [rqt_plot](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/tree/hydro-devel/rqt_plot/src/rqt_plot) will give you necessary API info for the latter.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris_chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2965/chris_chris/) on 2013-07-26**:
I need anything such that I should plot values of various variables while the program is running i.e)dynamically.